# Python: New Entity from Multiple Existing Entities

Tags: python, arguments, entities

I'm currently working to modify some python code to make it do what I want, but I keep running into the same problem.

The python code gets Entities from a JSON file.
I have edited that JSON file to add values, & I have successfully added them to the python script.
using those entities however has been a problem.
My biggest issue is that I keep needing to pass arguments to an application but I need 2 values to be delivered as a single value.

```json
{
  "maxWidth": "900",
  "maxHeight": "1100",
  "qualityNum": "90"
}
```

in the python script it gets the values with a

```py
    maxWidth = prefs.get('maxWidth', '600')
    maxHeight = prefs.get('maxHeight', '600')
```

but then when the script is run it needs to pass them as a single value `maxWidth`x`maxHeight` or `900x1100` from my example.

it then assembles the args

```py
args = [path, 'mogrify','-resize', maxWidth, '-quality', qualityNum, '-path', temp_dir, original_img_path]
```

I have tried & failed in the args assembly to mux them together, but it doesn't seem to be possible at that stage. So I thought the best thing to do is create a new entity `maxSize` & have that be a mix of the 2 with an `x` between them.

Unfortunately everything I have tried gives a syntax error.

Is there a way, in python, to create an entity value, or any other value I could use, that is made up of the text of 2 entities with manually entered text between them?

Comment: Not sure if I get you, but is this what you're looking for: `combined = f"{maxWidth}x{maxHeight}"`? Or if using the dictionary `combined = f"{dict_name['maxWidth']}x{dict_name['maxHeight']}"`

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was simple, I just couldn't find it anywhere `= f"{maxWidth}x{maxHeight}"` worked. If you put that as an Answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Before I create a new question, since you will likely know & I could edit this question to include it if you can answer both or create another, whichever you prefer, I'm adding an entity that has a list of values to another entity but the result ends up having the list enclosed in either `[ ]` or `" "` & search results just keep telling me how to use single & double quotes or triple double quotes to use them in a single string or that I don't need to escape double quotes. I'm sure it's simple for those who know the language but I don't & it's impossible to search for

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that one out, there's probably a better way to do it but I ended up splitting the list, `.extend()` the one I need to add in that spot, then `.extend()` the rest of the original list. It's good enough for what I need so I'm good with that. Just need your answer as an answer nothing more

Comment: If you want to concatenate two lists you can simply use `+`. Eg. `['a'] + ['b']` will give `['a', 'b']`. But `extend` also works.

Comment: the ['a'] + ['b'] would give me same problem, I need the arguments added from Split() from JSON to be in a certain spot in the middle of the list as it was. I needed it not be `['value1', 'value2', 'value3', ['added1', 'added2'], 'value4', 'value5']` or  `['value1', 'value2', 'value3', "'added1', 'added2'", 'value4', 'value5']` from the original `[valFirst, 'value2', valOther, addedListEntity, 'value4', valLast]`.
It worked out because using the extend I can add `if` values instead of finding a way to give a 'default' command that doesn't seem to exist & I don't need to create more entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [f-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
combined = f"{maxWidth}x{maxHeight}"
```

Or if using the dictionary:

```
combined = f"{dict_name['maxWidth']}x{dict_name['maxHeight']}"
```